# How to not move layout when keyboard appears android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, mobile

I have a problem. I saw a many questions about "How to move layout when keyboard appears" and so on. But I havent found any answer on how to **not** move layout when keyboard appears. I tried this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

and it helped. But now I have another problem. The keyboard move right under the EditText and covers the border:

[image]

Does anybody know, how to add a "margin" which can move any layout above keyboard by certain distance?